# Make table header fixed on scroll down but adapt on column hover

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have a table which holds values in cells shorten with ellipsis()text-overflow.

On scroll down I change the style of the table header so it remains fixed:

css:

```
.superResponsiveTable thead  {
  position:fixed;
  top:61px;
  background: white;
  z-index: 2;
  width:auto;
}
```

But when I do this, the header cells don't expand matching the rest of the column width when a cell of that column is hovered.

How to go around this?

I know how to do it with javascript but was wondering if could be done just with CSS?

Im using angularjs

[image]

Comment: Its not a good practice to set our custom properties to 'table elements'... Better divide header and data part as separate table's.Then adjust cell width as per your need using either css or JS.. :-)

Comment: Probably not possible with pure CSS. Once it gets the style `position:fixed;` it becomes detached from the rest of the `<table>`. Then it is no longer aware of the widths of the cells (which probably get their widths from the content) that they correspond with.

Comment: Is there an angular way of duplicating a complete div and display the same thing in two parts of the document. Like ng-model but with html content. Or is the only proper way of doing this with a custom directive which captures resize, hover, etc ... than gets viewport dimensions and restyles everything?